# Rounded corners on UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I am confused on how I would round corners, I've seen about **10 other posts** and non of them have helped me. Am I doing this correctly?

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" // in my ViewController.h

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

     self.backgroundLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
}
```

If somebody could help me out on this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What ten other posts? Cause if they did it this way they are wrong for what you have asked and shouldn't be accepted as answers. Also I don't believe there is anything called `self.backgroundLayer` you want `self.view.layer.cornerRadius`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, You are correct but set `self.backgroundLayer.layer.borderWidth`, I put following code might be helpful in your case.

For give **round Border** Of `UIView`.

Add `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` fram work. (*you've already done it*)

```
self.backgroundLayer = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(@"As You Want")];
self.backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.backgroundLayer.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0; // set cornerRadius as you want.
self.backgroundLayer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor; // set color as you want.
self.backgroundLayer.layer.borderWidth = 1.0; // set borderWidth as you want.
[self.view addSubView:self.backgroundLayer];
```

in your case give **border** of `UIView`.

Answer (score 12):

Try turning on `masksToBounds`. Also, what is backgroundLayer?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```